# How to understand this TMG's assembly code from the Version 6 Unix?

Tags: compiler, assembly, historical-unix

Early versions of Unix included Doug McIlroy's tool `tmg` ("transmogrifier"), an early compiler-compiler. TMG was implemented in Dennis Ritchie's assembly language as well as in TMGL itself (the language that TMG translates into assembly). 
Here is [TMG's manual](https://www.tuhs.org/Archive/Distributions/Research/1972_stuff/tmg.pdf) (1972). [Here](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/tree/Research-V6-Snapshot-Development/usr/source/tmg) is the complete source code from Version 6 Unix.

Since I am trying to understand how McIlroy's implementation of TMG worked, I am reading the file `tmgl.s`, a translation of `tmgl.t` done by TMG. And I am baffled by the following excerpts:

```
.1=.
1
.2=.
2
.3=.
```

And:

```
goto;..2
..3:null
..2:
```

I read the [PAL-11R](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/dec/pdp11/dos-batch/DEC-11-ASDB-D_PAL-11R_Assembler_Programmers_Manual_May71.pdf) and [Unix Assembly](http://www.tom-yam.or.jp/2238/ref/as.pdf) manuals, but do not recall an explanation.

Particularly:

- `.` means "location counter", but what is `.3=.`?
- `..` means "relocation counter", but what is `..3`?

(To make things worse, this kind of syntax seems to be only encountered in TMG implementation, not any other source file of Unix V6. And, to exclude the possibility of a corrupt code or phased out syntax, TMG sources actually compile in a [Python PDP-11 emulator](https://github.com/amakukha/PyPDP11) running Unix V6.)

Comment: Might be better suited for retrocomputing.stackexchange.com. I'd assume `=.` assigns the current location counter, and IIRC `.1`, `.2` etc. are "local" labels (can be redefined). If the syntax makes a differences between "location" and "relocation" labels, I'd expect the same for `..1` etc.

Comment: In the end of this research, I ported TMG from PDP-11 assembly to C. If anyone is interested: https://github.com/amakukha/tmg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.1`, `..1` have no special meaning. They're simple identifiers (labels, variables, etc). Unless declared with `.globl`, they will be local by default.

That was the case then and is still the case now. For instance, `gcc` is using `.` to prevent [static variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/471885/308316) from conflicting with symbols defined by the user.

> what is `.3=.`?

It assigns to the local symbol named `.3` the value of the location counter (the offset within the current segment).

Comment: Confirmed. I changed most of the prefix dots to `z`s, assembled, linked with the "squash" option and got exactly the same executable. Luckily, the answer is much simpler than I thought ^_^